# Users are able to edit other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this was asked before but I double check and made sure that the other questions solutions didn't work for me but anyway, Users are able to edit other users. All you gotta do is change the value id in the address bar and it'll sign you directly into the persons account. I need this fixed and to redirect to their edit page. I've tried multiple things with no luck! I'm not using Devise.

Here is my users_controller.rb,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, ]

  after_action :signed_in_after_register, only: :create 

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def dashboard 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end 

  def newsfeed
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == nil
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end

  def nav
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
  def posts
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end

  def welcome
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @post = Post.new(params[:post_id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
    redirect_to @dashboard_path unless @user
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully created!' }
        format.json { render :profile, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :profile, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    end
    def signed_in_after_register 
      session[:user_id] = @user.id 
   end
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :age, :profile_picture, :post, :body)
    end
end
```

Not to sure what other code you may need to see with this being a controller issue, If you do need any other code of mine just comment and ill edit my question right away! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, so if I got it correctly, you only want user to edit himself, but no other users. In that case, why do you need index?

Comment: @BroiSatse Maybe he's OK with allowing users to read one another's entries. There's no requirement that an indexed user profile must also be editable.

Comment: @MarsAtomic - true to that, just thought it would be nice to singular resource instead, but index is ruining it. ;)

Comment: Wait, I want users to still see each others information. I just don't want users changing other user's settings. haha

Comment: What do I need to change in the index? I have the index set so you can see all users.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent users from editing each other's profiles by implementing a `current_user` helper method and checking it from within your `edit` and `update` method.

Add the following method to app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

This helper will return a User object representing the current user in any view or controller.

Now in your `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`, replace your `update` method with the following:

```
def update
  if @user == current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :profile, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to some_other_path, notice: 'You do not have permission to edit the profile of another user.'
  end
end
```

You'll also have to set up your `users_controller#edit` method to use similar logic, but I'll leave that exercise to you, since the point is for you to learn something.